# Error while trying to compile headers in Ubuntu Jammy Jellyfish

Tags: ubuntu, linux-kernel, make, linux-headers

I am currently trying to compile the headers in Jammy Jellyfish, and I am running into the following error:

```
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-25-generic$ sudo make
  SYNC    include/config/auto.conf.cmd
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:213: archheaders] Error 2
```

Before running the make command, I copied the old .config file /boot/config-5.15.0-25-generic into the .config file in /usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-25-generic/

I've seen a few posts where this error has been posted, but I have not seen any answers that fix the issue. If there is more information needed, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: I also have the same issue after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04. I initially had errors for missing `flex` and `bison`. After manually installing those, I've run into this dead end. Lots of people having the same problem online, but no answers. This Korean page seems to have an answer, but I don't understand it: https://bigbigpark.github.io/error/linux_kernal/

Comment: Running into the same issue compiling 5.15.64. `make[1]: *** [kernel/Makefile:160: kernel/kheaders_data.tar.xz] Error 127 make: *** [Makefile:1896: kernel] Error 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to form up a solution posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39107811/no-rule-to-make-target-arch-x86-entry-syscalls-syscall-32-tbl-needed-by-arch

I tried to build a HP PC kernel module for the Linux Mint Vanessa. First thing - remove all spaces from the folder path you're building in (if there are any). I tried to build it also on my debian machine for the test. Here are my builds, hope it provides a solution. Edit your project Makefile.

Debian/Mint: original

```
#
# Makefile for hpuefi loadable kernel module
#
KVERS:=$(shell uname -r)
KSRC:=/lib/modules/$(KVERS)/build
KDIR:=/lib/modules/$(KVERS)/kernel/drivers/misc
DESTDIR:=
TARGET=hpuefi

obj-m:=$(TARGET).o

default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KSRC) SUBDIRS=$(PWD) modules
clean:
        $(RM) .*.cmd *.mod.c *.o *.ko *.order *.symvers -r .tmp*
install:
        install -D -m 0644 $(TARGET).ko $(DESTDIR)$(KDIR)/$(TARGET).ko
```

Debian before

```
user@machine:/media/user/usbdisk/SP58029/hpuefi-mod-1.0.3-deb$ make
make -C /lib/modules/5.10.0-19-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/media/user/usbdisk/SP58029/hpuefi-mod-1.0.3-deb modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-19-amd64'
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-19-common/Makefile:225: =============== ERROR ==============
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-19-common/Makefile:226: 'SUBDIRS' was removed in Linux 5.3
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-19-common/Makefile:227: Use 'M=' or 'KBUILD_EXTMOD=' instead
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-19-common/Makefile:228: ====================================
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-19-common/Makefile:229: *** ..  Stop.
make[1]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-19-common/Makefile:185: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.10.0-19-amd64'
make: *** [Makefile:13: default] Error 2
```

Debian fix

```
default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KSRC) M=$(PWD) modules
```

Linux Mint before

```
mint@mint:/media/mint/DAC4798DC4796D1F/swsetup/SP58029/HP_Utilities_for_Linux/hpuefi-mod-1.0.3$ sudo make
make -C /lib/modules/5.15.0-41-generic/build M= modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-41-generic'
make[2]: *** No rule to make target 'arch/x86/entry/syscalls/syscall_32.tbl', needed by 'arch/x86/include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [arch/x86/Makefile:213: archheaders] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.15.0-41-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:13: default] Error 2
```

Linux Mint fix:

```
default:
        $(MAKE) -C $(KSRC) M=$(shell pwd) modules
```